# Error when using importhtml function in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the google sheets function `importhtml()` in a script, to pass an encoded query parameter.

```
function recode(query) {
const value = encodeURIComponent(query).replace('%20','+');
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importhtml("xxx.com/?query='+value+'","table",1)');

}
```

I get an error "Exception: You do not have permission to call setFormula (line 5).'

Comment: Are you the owner of the Spreadsheet?  Perhaps you might try capitalizing IMPORTHTML . (that may be stupid but I don't  use formulas much) The is a getFormula issue on issue tracker so perhaps there is one of setFormula.

Comment: Although unfortunately, I cannot understand about your actual situation from your question, for example, when you use the function of `recode` as the custom function, such error occurs because of the current specification at Google side. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) How about this? If I misunderstood your actual situation, I apologize.